media_sideload_image only works on localhost and without return id or src
I'm trying to use media_sideload_image like in this question:
Can't upload image using media_sideload_image
it works on localhost with add_filter('https_ssl_verify', '__return_false'); for testing but it does not work on the actual remote site. The images are in another subdomain of the wordpress site like www.example.com and media.example.com.
Also, it does not return the id or src when the images are uploaded.
I'm using Wordpress 4.x

Can you include your code?  It most likely has something to do with the way you're mapping the URLs or generating the output - really tough to even begin debugging with what you've provided.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@TonyDjukic it's the exact same thing I did as the reference question.
